# How to share memory between processes created by fork()?

Tags: c, fork

In fork child, if we modify a global variable, it will not get changed in the main program.

Is there a way to change a global variable in child fork?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int glob_var;

main (int ac, char **av)
{
  int pid;

  glob_var = 1;

  if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
    /* child */
    glob_var = 5;
  }
  else {
    /* Error */
    perror ("fork");
    exit (1);
  }

  int status;
  while (wait(&status) != pid) {
  }
   printf("%d\n",glob_var); // this will display 1 and not 5.
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use shared memory with Linux in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656530/how-to-use-shared-memory-with-linux-in-c)

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can use shared memory (`shm_open()`, `shm_unlink()`, `mmap()`, etc.).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static int *glob_var;

int main(void)
{
    glob_var = mmap(NULL, sizeof *glob_var, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
                    MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

    *glob_var = 1;

    if (fork() == 0) {
        *glob_var = 5;
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    } else {
        wait(NULL);
        printf("%d\n", *glob_var);
        munmap(glob_var, sizeof *glob_var);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: could you provide a simple example

Comment: You'll need to look up shared memory; lots of examples on google. This allows two separate applications to use the same memory to store and read variables. When you `fork()` a process it creates a child process with a separate memory heap from the parent. Your parent will maintain its global variables while the child will allocate its own copies.

Comment: You can find some examples with a very good explanation [here](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html)

Comment: @md5: In the mmap function call the file descriptor handle is "-1". What does -1 signify ?

Comment: @TheLoneJoker. From man page of `mmap`:`however,  some
              implementations  require  fd to be -1 if MAP_ANONYMOUS (or MAP_ANON) is specified, and portable applications should ensure this`

Answer (score 12):

Changing a global variable is not possible because the new created process (child)is having it's own address space.

So it's better to use `shmget()`,`shmat()` from `POSIX` api

Or You can use `pthread` , since `pthreads`are sharing the `global`data and the changes in global variable is reflected in parent.

Then read some [Pthreads tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative solution.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

typedef struct
{
  int id;
  size_t size;
} shm_t;

shm_t *shm_new(size_t size)
{
  shm_t *shm = calloc(1, sizeof *shm);
  shm->size = size;

  if ((shm->id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, size, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)) < 0)
  {
    perror("shmget");
    free(shm);
    return NULL;
  }

  return shm;
}

void shm_write(shm_t *shm, void *data)
{
  void *shm_data;

  if ((shm_data = shmat(shm->id, NULL, 0)) == (void *) -1)
  {
    perror("write");
    return;
  }

  memcpy(shm_data, data, shm->size);
  shmdt(shm_data);
}

void shm_read(void *data, shm_t *shm)
{
  void *shm_data;

  if ((shm_data = shmat(shm->id, NULL, 0)) == (void *) -1)
  {
    perror("read");
    return;
  }
  memcpy(data, shm_data, shm->size);
  shmdt(shm_data);
}

void shm_del(shm_t *shm)
{
  shmctl(shm->id, IPC_RMID, 0);
  free(shm);
}

int main()
{
  int var = 1;
  shm_t *shm = shm_new(sizeof var);

  int pid;
  if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
  { /* child */
    var = 5;
    shm_write(shm, &var);
    printf("child: %d\n", var);
    return 0;
  }
  /* Wait for child to return */
  int status;
  while (wait(&status) != pid);
  /* */
  shm_read(&var, shm);
  /* Parent is updated by child */
  printf("parent: %d\n", var);
  shm_del(shm);
  return 0;
}
```

Build with:

```
$ gcc shm.c -o shm && ./shm
```