# Does fork() create a duplicate instance of all the variables and object created by the parent process for the child process?

Tags: c, multithreading, fork

Suppose I have a main process running and in its execution it has initialized some pointers and created some instances of a predefined structure.

Now if I fork this main process, is seperate memory allocated for the pointers?And are duplicate instances of the previously existing variables, data structures created for this new process?

As an example of my requirement consider -

```
struct CKT
{
  ...
}

main()
{
   ...Some computations with the structure and other pointers.....
   pid_t pid = fork();
   if(pid == 0) //child
   {
       ..some more computations with the structure...but I need a 
       ..separate instance of it with all the pointers in it as well..
   }
   else if(pid > 0) // parent
   {
       ..working with the original instance of the structure..
   }
   // merging the child process with the parent...
   // after reading the data of the child processes structure's data... 
   // and considering a few cases...
}
```

Can anyone explain how do I achieve this??

Comment: Your question is incomplete.

Comment: It has the same memory, except for the return value of fork().

Comment: @KirilKirov - yes it was incomplete...I am extremely sorry for that.. but now i have completed it...

Comment: http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/fork/create.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pointer and memory content both will be duplicated for the fork child.

all kind of data pointers, memory, variable will be duplicate in a separate memory for the child process created with fork. and you could not change pointers neither memory content from process child directly.

but you can change variable of parent process from child process using memory share

Refer to this link to see how to it: [How to share memory between process fork()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274786/how-to-modify-a-global-variable-in-child-fork)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It might not copy the memory space of the old process immediately, though. The OS will use copy-on-write where possible, copying each memory page the first time it is modified in either process.

COW is what makes one common use of `fork` (shortly followed by an `exec` in the child) efficient. The child process never actually uses most of the memory space inherited from the parent.

The copies in the new process will have exactly the same numeric addresses as they did in the old process, so all the pointers from the old process remain valid in the new process and point to the new process's objects. That's part of the point of virtual memory, it allows different process to refer to different physical memory using the same pointer value.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, theorically, the `fork` system call will duplicate, among other, the stack of the parent. In pratical, otherwise, there is a common method, named **copy-on-write**, used in that case.

It consists on copy a given parent's memory page only when the child's process is trying to modify this memory space. It allows to reduce the cost of the `fork` system call.

The one thing which is not copy is the return value of `fork`: 0 in the child, and the PID of the child in the father.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your forked process receives **copies** of all privately mapped memory (default memory mappings via `malloc`, `calloc`, stack frames, global variables)

Your child receives **shared copies** of all open file descriptors. Means those file descriptors will remain valid and open until **both** parent and child close them. Seeks on those file descriptors are also shared. If you wish to make a file descriptor child-private then you will have to `fdreopen` it. Otherwise it is **very** recommended to close all file descriptors you don't need in children immediately after forking.

Your child will receive the **same shared** `MAP_SHARED` mappings of memory. Those will continue to access the same physical memory shared between parent and child. This applies to all shared memory aquired through the `shm*` family of calls and `mmap`with `MAP_SHARED`.

Your child will **not** receive any mappings marked with `MADV_DONTFORK` flag via `madvise`. Those will become invalid in the child. This is not default behavior and you do not have to worry about it unless explicitly used.

Answer (score 0):

You might get the result you are looking for by using a shared memory segment. Use the `mmap` system call to create a shared memory segment, and put all your shared structures in that segment. Since you cannot use `malloc` on this segment (it's returned by the syscall as a pointer to the whole segment), you must copy manually the structures, and do the shared memory usage tracking by yourself.

Perhaps you can allocate your data first locally, then evaluate how much memory is used by them, and do the shared memory allocation with the correct size. It is also possible to reallocate the shared segment to a bigger size, in which case you will have to signal the realloc somehow from one end to the other (maybe by using the first integer pointed by the shared map to store that value?).

man pages:

- [mmap](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/mmap.html)
- [munmap](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/munmap.html)