# Sharing data between processes after fork() in C

Tags: c, fork

In the code below I need `num` to be read from parent process and used within forked process `child_proc()`. But it doesn't see what's read in the parent process. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int
is_prime(void);
void
child_proc(void);

int num = -1;

int
main(void)
{

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (-1 == pid) {
        printf("Internal error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (0 == pid) {
        printf("Starting child...\n");
        child_proc();
    } else {
        printf("Starting parent...\n");
        printf("Enter number to check:\n");
        scanf("%d", &num);  
        printf("You entered: %d\n", num);
    }
    sleep(1);
    if (pid == 0) {
        printf("Child Finished\n");
    } else {
        printf("Parent Finished\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

int
is_prime(void)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
        if ((num != i) && (num % i == 0)) {
            return 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

void
child_proc(void)
{
    if (num <= 1) {
        printf("Incorrect value: %d\n", num);
    } else {
        int rc = is_prime();
        if (0 == rc) {
            printf("%d is not a prime\n", num);
        } else {
            printf("%d is a prime\n", num);
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

After `fork(2)` the parent and the child become different processes and they don't share the same memory space. You need to use shared memory (see [How to share memory between process fork()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274786/how-to-share-memory-between-process-fork)) or maybe threads is better suited for you (https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/).