# Shared Memory struct in "On demand" Server in C

Tags: c, tcp, server, fork, shared-memory

I have to create for academic purpose an **"On-Demand Server"** that is based on the TCP protocol. The client each time sends a KEY and a VALUE that I have to store them in a **global** struct like the one bellow:

I use a function named "put" to store every KEY and VALUE to the struct and a "get" function that uses the key and finds the correct value:

My problem is that if a client makes a change in the struct the next one won't be able to know. I used semaphores in order to make the server wait until the child finishes and then accept the next child but I have still the same problem.

I read that I have to make the memory of this struct shared in order to make this work using mmaps but still I can't find a proper solution.

I make my first steps in server programming and every help would be great.

Comment: Simply don't `fork`. It makes no sense and serves no purpose.

Comment: Not the central topic of your question (which really has more to do with architectural issues then technique at this point) but do the sizes of `keys` and `values` really need to be so large.  As written, your struct requires an 8Mbyte minimum stack size.

Comment: In fact no! They have to be at least 51 size. But that is something I can change at any time. @ryyker

Comment: @n.m. You see in every example I have found on the Internet as far as "On demand server" is concerned fork() is used.

Comment: Have you seen the post _[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13274800/645128)_ ?.  It deals with sharing memory between forked processes, and has demo code to illustrate concept.

Comment: @ryyker Yes. I tried everything but I never succeed to take the correct results.

Comment: @ArisKantas - Your original post centers around how to share information (memory) between processes.  I do not see in your code example where you have tried _everything_ regarding that yet.  Try some of the things discussed, then come back and share your success, or ask another question.

Comment: You lock the entire data structure in order to make any change so only one process is running at a time. Might just as well have no concurrency at all.

Answer (score 1):

*My problem is that if a client makes a change in the struct the next one won't be able to know.*

As you noted, `mmap()` is part of the solution...
Shared memory needs of your application can be addressed with _[shm_open()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html)_, _[shm_unlink()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/shm_unlink)_, *[mmap](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mmap)*  etc. as illustrated in ***[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274786/how-to-share-memory-between-process-fork)*** post.  And ***[here](http://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/C/node27.html)*** for additional examples on shared memory

All of the essentials are summarized in the links, but this excerpt describes the basic concept:

> shm_open() creates and opens a new, or opens an existing, POSIX
>          shared memory object.  A POSIX shared memory object is in effect a
>          handle which can be used by unrelated processes to mmap(2) the same
>          region of shared memory.  The shm_unlink() function performs the
>          converse operation, removing an object previously created by
>          shm_open().

I also wanted to suggest that dynamic allocation of memory may be of use in creating space for your `struct` on an as-needed basis.  The size of members, as shown are excessively large,

```
char keys[4096];
char values[4096];
```

but in comments you state they only need to be 51 bytes.  The struct then can be created as a typedef:

```
struct keyvalue {
    char keys[51];
    char values[51];
} DATA;
```

The create an instance of a pointer to your struct:

```
DATA *pData = {0};
```

Which can then be sized on an as needed basis using standard *[malloc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc)*, and or *[realloc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc)*

```
pData = malloc(initialSize*sizeof(DATA));
```

As size requirements change, use the following to grow memory:

```
DATA *tmp = {0};
tmp = realloc(pData, newSize);
if(!tmp) return -1;//ensure memory allocation successful
pData = tmp;//tmp includes previous contents of pData, and more space
...  //continue using pData
```

Free pData when it is no longer needed.

```
free(pData);
```

To pass this struct in a function, the function might look like this:

```
void func1(DATA *d, int numElements)
{
    ...
    for(i=0;i<numElements;i++)
    {
        strcpy(d[i]->keys, "some key");
        strcpy(d[i]->values, "some value");
    }
    ...
}
```

To call that function with a copy of `pData`, if say it had a 1000 elements:

```
func1(pData, 1000);
```

Comment: At first, thank you very much for your detailed answer. I now have the following question. If I want to create 1000 instances of this struct and use them in a function how to I call the struct instance [i] etc?

Comment: Yes.  it would look like `pData[i]->keys`, or `pData[i]->values`.  See edit to my answer for illustration.

Comment: Thank you again! So if i use your way every child will be able to use the struct and make changes that are visible to the other chlidren?

Comment: @ArisKantas - if your use of the functions discussed is implemented correctly, and your architecture is sound, yes.  There is no reason to expect it wouldn't.  Start off with a small project to prove the concept, then integrate your working code into your final project.

Comment: The creation of the instance must be made in the main()? And also my problem is that the function I must use put() and get() must have strictly only the parameters I show in my question. So I can't pass the DATA pointer or the numElements.

Comment: If the prototypes of `get` and `put` are required as you have shown, that forces you to have a _process global_ copy of your struct, i.e. one for each client.  Then you would write to, or read from a single element of the that process global using the functions.  i.e. strcpy(pData->keys, "key");  The `put` and `get` prototypes force the issue.

Comment: @ArisKantas - if I am not able to respond right away, it is because I have been called away for awhile.  Leave any questions and I (or someone else) will try to answer when I return.  Thank you.

Comment: Could you please show me how can I use shmget and shmat properly in my exaple in order to make this work?