# Opetrative Systems : How do i increment the childs with forks

Tags: operating-system

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
int x = 10;
pid_t p = fork(), t = fork(), s = fork();
printf("PID = %d -> pai: %d -> x = %d\n", getpid(), getppid(), x);
return 0;
}
```

hi. I need to change the code above, need increment 2 (value on x) to each of the 7 childs.
i tried with if but the code repeat the fathers.

Comment: I believe you'd need to explicitly have some shared memory between them. When forking, the child is given a copy (on-write) of the parent's memory. `x` will have the same address in all processes, but they aren't the same variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to share memory between process fork()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274786/how-to-share-memory-between-process-fork)